# Stop Binance Futures API from printing candlestick data as a list

Tags: python-3.x, binance

When using the Binance Futures API to get candlestick data, the call prints all the data it retrieves from the socket. This gets in the way of whatever you're trying to make.
https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is by changing the source in the library. Make the necessary changes then reinstall the library from the git repo you cloned. The changes are:
From the main directory, open `binance_f/impl/restapiinvoker.py` and make every line that has a  `print()` function a comment.
Then just reinstall the lib with `python3 setup.py install`.

No offence to the creators but I think the API is horribly overengineered and unnecessarily complicated and is a nightmare to work with because it lacks docs for implementation. The service is awsome though so it makes that worth it.